# Does the New World of Darkness have a Dark Ages book?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, historical-settings

Other than the *Dark Era* books, is there a source book for Chronicles of Darkness for running games set in the Dark Ages? The Dark Era books have good thematic information but are a bit light on mechanical aspects like equipment, skills, merits, and that kind of thing.

Comment: If you can let us know what primarily you are interested above everything else (e.g. medieval weapons, additional fighting styles, pirate equipment etc...) you could receive a more helpful answer.

Comment: Well...I've always had this idea that the Storyteller system (if that's what it's called, I'm not massively familiar with WoD) would be a good system to run a low magic, non combat oriented fantasy game (systems like D20 and its derivatives are too "high powered").   

I've already started planning how I'll implement standard fantasy archetypes, I was mainly looking for historic mechanics to use as a base.

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no specific supplements for Chronicle of Darkness that deal with the mechanical minutiae of each Dark Eras setting. A list of books in the COFD and NWOD series can be found here: http://www.wodcodex.com/wiki/Books . Happy hunting!